# Import/no-unresolved for static images resources

Tags: react-native, eslint

I got this linting error on my project for a while now.

```
Casing of ../../assets/logo/logo.png does not match the underlying filesystem
```

Where on my filesystem I have

```
../../assets/logo/logo@2x.png
../../assets/logo/logo@1x.png
```

The issue links to [No Unresolved Module](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unresolved.md)

How to solve this issue so that the import resolver knows to that logo@2x/1x.png is a valid import for logo.png?

Answer (score 3):

[An issue](https://github.com/Intellicode/eslint-plugin-react-native/issues/32) related to React-Native's import resolver open but no solution to fix the problem is available or discussed.

For now, I'll be ignoring this error for images on my `.eslintrc` file

```js
    rules: {
       'import/no-unresolved': [2, { ignore: '\.(png|webp|jpg|$' }] 
    }
```

Please let me know if there are other solutions or fix to this issue